# InvalidArgumentException: Enabling or disabling Dynamic Partitioning is not supported at the moment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

When I try to run `terraform apply`in my project, it throws the following error:

```
 Error: Error Updating Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream: "delivery"
│ InvalidArgumentException: Enabling or disabling Dynamic Partitioning is not supported at the moment
│ 
│   with module.shippeo-api.module.v1.aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.event-eta,
│   on ../../modules/api_gateway_v1/kinesis.tf line 12, in resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "event-eta":
│   12: resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "event-eta" {
│ 
╵
```

because of this part:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "event-eta" {
  name        = local.firehose_delivery_stream
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = var.integration_role_arn
    #bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.jsonfiles.arn
    bucket_arn = var.target_bucket_arn

    prefix              = "!{partitionKeyFromLambda:apiPath}/!{partitionKeyFromLambda:authorizerClientId}/!{timestamp:yyyy}/!{timestamp:MM}/!{timestamp:dd}/!{timestamp:HH}/"
    #prefix = "!{timestamp:yyyy}/!{timestamp:MM}/!{timestamp:dd}/!{timestamp:HH}/"
    error_output_prefix = "error/!{timestamp:yyyy}/!{timestamp:MM}/!{timestamp:dd}/!{timestamp:HH}/!{firehose:error-output-type}"



    dynamic_partitioning_configuration {
      enabled = true
    }
```

I already have the latest version in my provider.tf files:

```
  required_providers {
    archive = {
      source  = "hashicorp/archive"
      version = "2.2.0"
    }
    aws     = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.72.0"
    }
  }
```

However, when I check `terraform version`on my terminal, I get this:

```
Terraform v1.0.7
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.72.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.1.4. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

I already tried `terraform init -upgrade`but that didn't make a difference either.I also manually downloaded terraform's new version from the website but my terminal still shows 1.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's limitation at the moment. Currently, you can enable the dynamic partitioning only while creating a new delivery stream but not on existing delivery streams.

From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/dynamic-partitioning.html):

> Important You can enable dynamic partitioning only when you create a
> new delivery stream. You cannot enable dynamic partitioning for an
> existing delivery stream that does not have dynamic partitioning
> already enabled.

It means, if you want to use the feature currently, you will have to create a new stream.

Comment: deleting the previous one using console and then doing terraform apply seems to have worked! :D